# is it possible to force fail compile if a type isn't specified with flow?

Tags: node.js, flowtype

Is it possible to detect if we forget to set a type to a variale with flow for example ?

like :

```
let mystring: string = "hello";
let mynumber = 54;
```

if I run flow, can he detect that the variable mynumber hasn't type and pop an error ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a lint for that. As far as flow is concerned, this is just type elision, which is fine and common. Flow still knows exactly what type `mynumber` is, and will keep track of it and error accordingly. There are all kinds of [lints](https://flow.org/en/docs/linting/rule-reference/) around usage of *untyped* data (`any`, `Object` etc.) but as `mynumber` has a perfectly defined type as far as flow is concerned, none of these lints apply.

Anyway, the goal of using flow should probably not be to make sure that every type has explicitly been written in, as this can be very onerous and unnecessary. This is why flow supports elision and things like the existential type. Flow does a pretty good job of telling you when you really need types.